# Welches Wort anstelle von "programmatisch"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request, adjective, phrase-request

Das Wort *[programmatisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/programmatisch)* ist definiert als:

> 1. einem Programm, einem Grundsatz entsprechend
> 2. richtungweisend, zielsetzend

Sucht man nach dem Begriff, fällt auf, dass der Begriff häufig in Verbindung mit der Politik verwendet wird. Ich habe aber, abgesehen von Foreneinträgen und so, keine Quelle gefunden, in der auch nur annäherungsweise Bezug zur Programmierung vorhanden ist.

Dennoch höre ich bei Gesprächen mit Kollegen häufig Sätze der Art:

> Die Mehrfachvererbung ist ein Versuch "wirkliche" Objektrelationen programmatisch abzubilden.
>
> Lässt sich das auch irgendwie programmatisch lösen, so dass wir z. B. einen Windows-Dienst laufen lassen, der gestorbene Services automatisch wieder startet?
>
> Ich erstelle je nach Anzahl der Objekte in einem Array programmatisch Buttons.

Im Kontext ist mit *programmatisch* was ganz anderes gemeint, als das Wort eigentlich bedeutet. Ich bin mir nur nicht ganz sicher, was genau. Die Idee dahinter ist mir durchaus klar, nur fällt es mir schwer in den Sätzen ein treffendes Adjektiv zu setzen, das der eigentlichen Bedeutung entspricht. Oder gar überhaupt eine Phrase. Was mir in den Sinn kam, sind Dinge wie *im Code* oder *softwaretechnisch*. Beides klingt recht umständlich und gebrochen.

Ich habe auch versucht, den Begriff *programmatisch* betreffend dieser Verwendung zu definieren und anhand der Definition Synonyme zu finden, bin aber auch daran grundlegend gescheitert. Offen gestanden bereits an der Definition.

Ganz losgelöst von den drei Beispielen: Welche Wörter (optimalerweise ein Adjektiv) oder Wortgruppen beschreiben, was häufig versucht wird mit *programmatisch* auszudrücken?

Comment: Darf man vielleicht "programmlich" sagen? Zu Bsp.3: "Das Programm erstellt ... Buttons" ad 2: "Läßt sich auch derart lösen" (dass es per Programm geschieht ergibt sich aus "Windowsdienst").

Comment: Ich glaube, die Formulierung ergib sich aus dem englischen "programmatically", das ebenfalls sehr häufig verwendet wird, um auszudrücken, dass man etwas im Code und nicht etwa per Einstellung oder so machen möchte.

Comment: programmatisch kenne ich als "automatisch vom Programm durchgeführt". Die Software löst etwas, manuelle Eingriffe sind nicht erforderlich. Bsp. Es gibt zwei Prozesse (P). P2 benötigt Ergebnisse von P1, kann also nicht vor Ende von P1 starten. Programmatisch bedeutet in diesem Fall, dass ein übergeordneter Prozess das Ende von P1 bemerkt und automatisch P2 startet, dabei das P1-Ergebnis übergibt. Nicht programmatisch wäre es, das P1-Ergebnis anzuzeigen und P2 mit Eingabe des P1-Ergebnisses manuell zu starten. Das wohl treffendste Synonym ist m.E.: programmgesteuert.

Answer (score 6):

oder auch **programmgesteuert**, **per Programm**, **softwaremäßig**, **softwareseitig**.

Comment: *Softwareseitig* gefällt mir gut.

Comment: Mit "programmatisch" ist die Art und Weise gemeint, wie ein Programm erstellt wird. Wenn ein Teil des Programms durch Klicken und Ziehen der Maus, also ohne Eingabe von "echtem" Quelltext, erzeugt wird, ist das nicht programmatisch. Nur wenn der Code wirklich geschrieben (also nicht auf einer graphischen Oberfläche zusammengeklickt) wurde, wird dieser Teil der Software programmatisch erzeugt.

Answer (score 5):

Vielleicht sollte man akzeptieren, dass lebende Sprachen einem stetigen Wandel unterworfen sind, und dass Wörter im Lauf der Zeit ihre Bedeutungen verändern. Wörterbücher und Regelwerke hinken daher zwangsweise dem tatsächlichen Gebrauch der Sprache hinterher (manchmal sogar um Jahrzehnte).

Daher sollte man, meiner Meinung nach, eine dritte Definition in die Wörterbücher aufnehmen:

---

**programmatisch**

- (3) Im Kontext der Informationsverarbeitung: Durch Bearbeiten des Quelltextes eines Programms.

---

Buttons und andere Elemente kann ein Softwareentwickler heutzutage häufig mit einem graphischen Editor mit ein paar Mausklicks erzeugen und in das Programm einbinden, ohne selbst eine einzige Zeile Programmcode zu schreiben. Genau das ist mit "programmatisch" nicht gemeint.

Wenn aber ein Button auf der Benutzeroberfläche erscheint, weil ein paar Zeilen Code durchlaufen werden, die ein Programmierer mit seinen Fingern in eine Tastatur getippt hat, ohne mit der Maus per drag&drop eine Bedienelement zu erstellen, dann wird der Button programmatisch erzeugt.

Comment: Obwohl das die einzige Antwort ist, die mir halbwegs plausibel erscheint, habe ich den Eindruck, dass diese Deutung offensichtlich nicht wirklich weit verbreitet und noch kein (Programmierer-) Allgemeinwissen ist. Wie sonst könnte diese Frage so viele verschiedene Antworten generieren, wenn die Bedeutung klar wäre?

Comment: @Clemens: Das könnte daran liegen, dass die anderen Antworten nicht von Programmierern stammen. (Nur eine Vermutung, ich weiß nicht welche Berufe die anderen Antworter ausüben)

Comment: Klar, gut möglich.

Comment: Ich glaube, das ist nicht das "programmatisch" was Em1 in seiner Frage meint...

Answer (score 4):

Sehr, sehr schwierig.

In den anderen Antworten ist schon so ziemlich alles an Möglichkeiten vertreten - außer vielleicht *programmbasiert*.

Aber vielleicht gibt es noch einen Aspekt zu bedenken: Es könnte ja sein, dass sich die Verwendung des Wortes *programmatisch* in dieser Bedeutung gerade einbürgert. Da wird man nicht sonderlich viel dagegen machen können. Vielleicht geht es diesem Wort demnächst so wie dem armen *nachhaltig*, das langsam die Zusatzbedeutung **supermegaprima* anzunehmen scheint.

Comment: Du hast recht. Diese Verwendung des Wortes wird früher oder später im Duden aufgenommen. Auf die Definition, und vor allen Dingen die Auflistung der Synonyme, bin ich gespannt. Aber den Job wollte ich den Jungs und Mädels des Dudens nicht vorwegnehmen. ;)

Comment: Achja, *programmbasiert* gefällt mir.

Comment: @Em1: Man könnte vielleicht eine Art langfristiges Bingo oder Trinkspiel draus machen: Jeder macht eine Liste mit Synonymen und in 15 Jahren trifft man sich und trinkt für jeden Treffer einen. Sinnvollerweise sollten dann aber noch ein paar andere Wörter mit aufgenommen werden, damit sich's auch lohnt :)

Answer (score 3):

Hier meine Vorschläge:

**algorithmisch**

**durch eine Routine**

**mittels eines Programms**

Passt nicht auf alle deine Beispiele, aber vielleicht als Denkanstoß.

Answer (score 3):

Die erwähnten Beispiele meinen jeweils etwas völlig verschiedenes, dass man gar nicht korrekt in einem Wort fassen kann. Und wie gesagt, *programmatisch* ist definitiv falsch nach der oben angeführten Definition.

> Die Mehrfachvererbung ist ein Versuch "wirkliche" Objektrelationen
>   programmatisch abzubilden.

In diesem Satz bedeutet es *softwaretechnisch*, was man aber getrost weglassen kann, weil 
es aus dem Kontext heraus ersichtlich ist, dass es sich sehr speziell auf die Softwaretechnik bzw. OO-Programmierung bezieht. (Man stelle sich mal Mehrfachvererbung in anderen Kontexten vor, im Zoo z.B. das wäre sicherlich interessant.)

> Lässt sich das auch irgendwie programmatisch lösen, so dass wir z.B.
>   einen Windows-Dienst laufen lassen, der gestorbene Services
>   automatisch wieder startet?

Gemeint ist hier doch eigentlich: Wie können wir X *implementieren*, damit Y funktioniert.

*implementieren*: mit X irgendwas umsetzen, abbilden, realisieren. Soweit ich weiß, gibt es davon leider kein Adverb. Es macht in diesem Kontext auch einen Unterschied ob man meint, dass für das Problem X ein Algorithmus existiert - also eine algorithmische Lösung - oder das Problem X tatsächlich mit diesem Code-Snippet an jener Stelle behandelt werden kann - das würde die konkrete Implementierung betreffen. Das sind erfahrungsgemäßig zwei ganz verschiedene Dinge.

> Ich erstelle je nach Anzahl der Objekte in einem Array programmatisch
>   Buttons.

Der Satz bezieht sich schon auf eine Implementierung, also ist hier vielmehr die konkrete Automatisiserung gemeint:  Ich erstelle X Objekte *automatisch*, je nach der Anzahl von Y. 
Das es innerhalb eines Programms also Software passiert, darf man wohl einfach annehmen.

Ich würde sagen es gibt eine ganze Reihe von Möglichkeiten für präzise Formulierungen, aber insgesamt macht es eher den Eindruck als wüssten die meisten selbst nicht so richtig, was sie eigentlich meinen.

Answer (score 1):

1. Die Mehrfachvererbung ist ein Versuch "wirkliche" Objektrelationen programmatisch abzubilden.

   --> Programmtechnisch, softwaretechnisch, in Software zu gießen, abstrakt, regelbasiert, statisch, unklar :D
2. Lässt sich das auch irgendwie programmatisch lösen, so dass wir z.B. einen Windows-Dienst laufen lassen, der gestorbene Services automatisch wieder startet?

   --> Automatisch
3. Ich erstelle je nach Anzahl der Objekte in einem Array programmatisch Buttons.

   --> Automatisch

Answer (score 1):

Man spricht unter Programmierern auch von `dynamischen` oder `generierten` Objekten, Lösungen, Schleifen, Antworten, etc. - für mich hören sich die bislang genannten Varianten nach sehr gezungenen Übersetzungen an.

Comment: Nun gut. Was schlägst du denn vor? Und ich verstehe nicht, inwiefern hier *dynamisch* und *generisch* relevant sind. Ob die Implementierung *hard coded* ist oder nicht, ist doch egal, bzgl. der Verwendung dieses Wort zumindest.

Comment: Mein Vorschlag war eben jener: In einem Grossteil der Fälle ist mit "programmatisch" gemeint, dass etwas vom Programm gesteuert oder erstellt wird, und oftmals kann man das auch mit `dynamisch` oder `generiert` ausdrücken, selbst wenn die Nuance eine andere ist. z.B. eine *programmatisch* erzeugte Mitteilung könnte ebensogut eine *dynamisch erzeugte* oder *programmgenerierte* Mitteilung sein.

Comment: Verstehe. Bin mir nur nicht sicher. Wenn ich von einer dynamischen oder generischen Lösung rede, erwarte ich beispielsweise etwas in der Art `T Find<T>()`. Wenn ich nach einer *programmatischen* Lösung suche, kann es aber eben auch *hard coded* sein, oder einen bestimmten Typ erwarten, also: `int Find()`.

Comment: `programmatisch` verstehe ich als "mit Hilfe eines Programmes", in dem Sinn passt `dynamisch` oder `generiert` auch auf *hard coded*, selbst wenn ein Programmier wohl *hard coded* kaum `dynamisch` nennen würde - im Gegenteil. Der Sprachgebrauch hängt hier von der Perspektive ab. Eine `programmatisch` erzeugte Antwort, also eine "mit Hilfe eines Programmes" erzeugte Antwort, ist für mich durchaus eine `generierte` Antwort, ganz gleich wie diese im Programm intern entschieden wird.